# Sorting lists, which algorithm is appropriate to use?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, arraylist, linked-list

I've come to understand that when sorting say a LinkedList, it's better to use merge sort because when you want to put something in the middle of the list you do it in O(1) (constant) time and O(1) memory. therefore merge sort can be done without using up extra space.

My questions are: which sorting algorithm should one use on an ArrayList? Does it matter which datatype you're sorting?

Please correct me if I'm wrong about LinkedList or let me know if I've missed something (some argument for using merge for example).

Answer (score 0):

Short of copying a list to an array, sorting the array, and then creating a new list, the fastest list sort is a bottom up merge sort:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Bottom-up_implementation_using_lists

Assuming ArrayList is implemented as an array of pointers to objects, and that sorting an ArrayList sorts the pointers as opposed to sorting the objects, then merge sort is faster than quick sort, since merge sort does more moves but fewer compares than quick sort, and in this case, only the pointers are being moved, while the compares involve indirection via the pointers.

Answer (score 0):

As I found, you are seeking for in-place sorting algorithms (to know more see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_algorithm)):

> In computational complexity theory, the strict definition of in-place algorithms includes all algorithms with O(1) space complexity, the class DSPACE(1).

Moreover, you can see list of in-place sorting algorithms [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Comparison_of_algorithms).
Heap sort and smooth sort are kinds of these algorithms.